# How to build specific service using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How do I target my build using `docker-compose` **to one** of the services I have in `docker-compose.yml`?

My `docker-compose.yml` for example:

```
version: '3'

services:
  admin:
    image: 8205037.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/admin:latest
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./.docker/Dockerfile-admin

  www:
    image: 233232037.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/www:latest
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-www
```

And how to build only the www without change the file? I want to run something like this:

`docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.yml build --target www`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the target :)

```
docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.yml build www
```

Answer (score 1):

```
docker-compose -f **(path docker-compose file)** build **(container name)**
```

If it's the first time.

```
docker-compose -f **(path docker-compose file)** up -d **(container name)**
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply this command: `docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build <service_name>`

In your case: `docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build www`